# Finding a minimal containing rectangle from a given set of rectangles

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, computational-geometry

The problem is as follows:

Given a finite set of rectangles ($S\subset\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$), build a data structure that will support the following operations:

- Check, receives a rectangle $r\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, and returns true iff there is a rectangle $c\in S$ so that $r_x \leq c_x$ and $r_y \leq c_y$.
- Get, receives a rectangle $r\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, and returns the minimal member of $S$ (that is, a member with a minimal area - $c_x c_y$) that contains $r$ (i.e., $r_x \leq c_x$ and $r_y \leq c_y$).
- Insert, receives a rectangle $r\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, and adds it to $S$.
- Remove, receives a rectangle $r\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, and removes it from $S$.

The four procedures have to be efficient, measuring efficiency by $m$ and $n$, where $m$ is the number of different widths in $S$ and $n$ is the number of different heights in $S$.

Space efficiency has to be no worse than $O(mn)$ (that is, linear to the number of elements in $S$).

Comment: What is a "rectangle" here?  The notation "$r\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$" formally implies that $r$ is a single point in the plane.

Comment: The rectangle $\left(r_x,\: r_y\right)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ is the rectangle bound by $\left(0,\: 0\right)$, $\left(r_x,\: 0\right)$, $\left(0,\: r_y\right)$ and $\left(r_x,\: r_y\right)$.

Comment: I don't know of any existing data structure that addresses `Get`. Finding the dominating point (same thing as containing rectangle) $c$ such that $c_x \cdot c_y$ is minimized might be a new question. I would start by trying to design a *decomposition scheme* to support `Get` (see [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.94.8006))

Answer (score 2):

Check, insert, and remove can be accomplished by a data structure for dynamically maintaining 2D maxima ([this 2011 paper by Brodal and Tsakalidis](http://www.cs.au.dk/~gerth/papers/icalp11.pdf) presents a history of the problem including their new algorithm). I have no idea how to do get.